# n is null in SWFObject v1.5:

Tags: internet-explorer, flash, swfobject

I am using swfobject.js V1.5 in Mozilla its working fine but when i run the application in IE it shows

**N is NULL in swfobject.js**

```
Because of this the total page is not loaded....

 **In this line N.innerhtml**
```

Any Ideas or suggestions to solve this problem...

Answer (score 1):

you may giving a wrong html tag address like wrong id, thus swfobject can't find where to put  generated html. I made the same mistake just 5 minutes ago and noticed that i'd given a wrong id address after i fix it, the problem solved :)